# Most efficient data structure for inserting and sorting

Tags: sorting, data-structures, linked-list, insert, red-black-tree

I need an efficient data structure for storing, I need to insert and maybe order. However, keeping the order after every insert is not necessary and I think that sortings are much less than inserts.

I was considering red-black trees but I'm not sure how fast it is inserting a node in an RB tree (compared to inserting it in a list for example); however, sorting in an RB tree is much more time-efficient.

What data structure is the most efficient for that?

Thanks for your time

Comment: *" for storing"*: you mean "for sorting"? Also, you are asking multiple questions... A question should be *one* question only.

Comment: When you want to sort, do you really need the complete sort order, or just the first K minimum/maximum values from the collection?

Comment: @trincot for "storing" I mean for actually storing data inside. When needed, I need a complete sort. Also, my question is about "efficiency" and I believe efficiency includes both speed and memory, so my question is actually one.

Comment: You are also asking "What is the minimum percentage of sortings for making a tree more efficient than a list?" -- So you are asking for a percentage, a data structure, an algorithm (2x: for presumably inserting and sorting on that data structure), and the space complexity of those algorithms.

Comment: @trincot that is also strictly related to efficiency. Also, I'm not asking for an algorithm (I already know how to insert and sort over a data structure). I'm just asking for a data structure for my purpose only, I don't think it's too broad. I'm just asking a question (which is my first one on StackOverflow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure how fast it is inserting a node in an RB tree (compared to inserting it in a list for example

Insertion has this average time complexity:

- RB tree (also worst case): O(logn)
- Sorted list: O(n)
- Unsorted list: O(1)

Traversing all values in sorted order:

- RB tree: O(n)
- Sorted list: O(n)
- Unsorted list: O(nlogn)

So for asymptotically increasing data sizes, insertion will eventually run faster on an RB than on a sorted list, although for small sizes the list can be faster (as it has less constant overhead). The actual tipping point will depend on implementation aspects, including the programming language and the structure of the values to compare. But insertion into a non sorted list will of course outperform both.

Sorting a list on demand as is needed for an unsorted list, has a cost, but it is "only" O(nlogn) compared to O(n). So if sorting doesn't have to happen that frequently, it may be a viable option. Again, the tipping point -- as where the overall running time of several inserts and sorts is faster than the alternatives -- depends on implementation aspects.

> What data structure is the most efficient for that?

In practice I have found B+ trees to be a good choice for fast insertion. Just like RB trees they have O(logn) insertion time, but one can tune the data structure with varying block sizes, trying to find out which one works best for your actual case. This is not possible with RB trees. Also B+ trees have the sorted list sitting in a linked list of sorted blocks, so iteration in sorted order is trivial. Nothing much is going to beat the speed of that.

Another interesting alternative is a [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list). It resembles a B+ tree a bit, but its operations are easier to implement. It uses a factor more memory (same complexity) by the absence of blocks and more pointers.

Which one will work the best depends on implementation/platform factors. In the end you'll want to implement some alternatives and compare them with benchmark tests.

Comment: So, talking about RB trees and unsorted linked lists, in my scenario choosing a tree instead of a list is like paying a log(n) for every insert to eventually save a log(n) for every sorted lookup. So, according to this statement, if there are more inserts than sorting I should use a linked list over an RB tree; also I think that the multiplicative constants in an RB tree (for insert and balancement) are bigger.

Comment: *"is like paying a log(n) for every insert to eventually save a log(n) for every sorted lookup"*: it doesn't work that way. RB: O(log(n)) + O(n) = O(n) and List: O(1) + O(nlogn) = O(nlogn). So if you alternate insert with sort, the complexity for RB is better. If you perform n inserts and then sort those n, then RB: O(log1+..+log(n)) + O(n) = O(nlogn) and List: nO(1) + O(nlogn) = O(nlogn). Also, you cannot really deduce actual time spent on these steps based on time complexity. For a given n, one O(n) algorithm may run 100 times slower than another O(n) algorithm.